# Naming files after splitting them with split command within a pipeline

Tags: bash, unix, split, find

I've been recently dealing with splitting large files and processing them further.

My current pipe is very simple>

```
find .  -type f -size +100M | split -b 100M
```

But what this does is not exactly what I'm after. I would like splitted files named similarly to input files to split function, for example> inputs of find are>

```
file1
file2
file3
```

I would like output in the lines of for example

```
file101 file102 ...
file201 file202 ...
file301 file302 ...
```

I tried with >

```
split -b 100M -d $(find .  -type f -size +1000M) $(find .  -type f -size +1000M)
```

but it doesn't work as I wish, it throws error!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split` doesn't read the filenames from standard input. You have to give the filename as an argument. You can do that with the `-exec` option to `find`. Use the `{}` placeholder to substitute the filename for both the input file and the output prefix arguments.

```
find .  -type f -size +100M -exec split -b 100M -d {} {} \;
```

Comment: Aaaaah, that explains a lot. Thank you very much!

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question - how to name those outptut files?

Comment: I figured it, one must + instead of \; Thanks again.

Comment: That won't work. You can only give one input file at a time to `split`. If you use `+` it will try to split them all in a single command.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to use the filename as the prefix argument to `split`.

Comment: Interesting, I works perfectly at the moment. If any trouble occurs, I will know what to correct.

Comment: It's probably putting the split version of file1 in file2xx.